# Necessity of the airliner tag

Tags: discussion, retagging

We now have [20 questions with the airliner tag](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airliner).

Looking through them, there are **very** few, if any, that actually need it.

Most of them are either generic large/transport category airplane questions (because there are Boeing and Airbus airplanes that are private too) or generic questions that apply to all jet aircraft or all pressurized aircraft.

There are a few that apply only to the ***airlines*** (and not specifically *airliners*), but those can be tagged [airline-operations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airline-operations).

I propose that we retag the existing questions appropriately and remove the tag altogether unless someone finds questions that it is actually relevant for.

Comment: As opposed to [tag:airliner] I would rather see [tag:transport-category-aircraft] / [tag:commuter-category-aircraft] (or whatever ICAO's equivalent terms are). Otherwise an airframe specific tag would probably be more sensible than generic "airliner".

Answer (score 2):

We have not acted on this and now there are 103 questions that use the tag.

For some of them it appears to be superfluous, but for others it might be "SEO-friendly", given that apparently users are quite prone to use `airliner` for commercial aircrafts.

voretaq7 suggests in the comments to substitute the tag with a more verbose and ICAO-friendly tag. My take would be to make them synonyms, with [airliner](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airliner) the master.

Comment: Do you want [airliner] to turn into [transport-category-aircraft] or vice versa?

Comment: @raptortech97 I would make `airliner` the master, given that so far we are 103-0

Comment: Then I don't understand the point of synonymizing them. No-one's using [transport-category-aircraft], so it seems like we could just let it be.

Comment: @raptortech97 my suggestion was to include the ICAO terms in the tag list, but maybe I'm missing something on how tag synonyms work, you you want you can explain to me in chat

Comment: sorry, I can't get chat working on mobile right now. I'll have access to a computer in about 12 hours